# How to add to second / non-default Firebase Realtime DB through Zapier

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, zapier

I currently have 2 Firebase Realtime DB

meetingapp (default)
meetingnotes

They are 2 different Databases under the same account.

The first one (meetingapp) has the following structure:
/ meetingapp / prod / uid

the second one (meetingnotes) has the following structure:
/ meetingnotes / label / definition

With Zapier I can easily add to the path /meetingapp/prod/uid, but I cannot find any reference on how to refer to the path of the 2nd db.

I think this is the problem with having 2 "roots", and I am hoping someone has successfully write to the 2nd root.